# F3 key not working (on High Sierra 10.13.2)

Tags: keyboard, high-sierra

Pretty straight forward question: I just updated to High Sierra 10.13.2 last night, and my <kbd>F3</kbd> key isn't allowing me to see all the windows I have opened. I have tried using multiple different keyboards.  Does anyone know how to fix?

Comment: i just tried it on my old iMac with High Sierra and it works.  Do you have the f3 key dined somewhere?

Comment: what does dined mean?

Comment: lol.. sorry, i meant defined.

Comment: not to my knowledge, i have never messed around with assigning keys to any other uses

Comment: What about the other function keys?  Do they work?  Have you tried holding the Fn key while pressing F3?

Comment: all the other ones work, and yes ive tried the fn button and it doesnt do anything

Comment: Does `ctrl` + `↑` (arrow-up) work? If so, at least you will know that Mission Control is active. Have you checked your settings under `System Preferences` -> `keyboard` -> tab: `key combinations` ?

Comment: Hi, did you figure out any solution ? I have exactly the same issue with high sierra 1.13.5, wired keyboard, the ctrl + ↑ works well. Thanks